# VBA select case ignoring single digit (LEN) cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a select case which is meant to look and find set exact cases. What is baffling me is, its executing on cases that have 2 digits but not on single digit cells. Plainly put, Case "B" and "C" are executing in the else statement instead of their respective cases, any pointers will be appreciated...

```
Public Function cartMaxCalc(i As Long)

Dim contQty
Set contQty = Cells(i, 6)
Dim contTypeRange
Set contTypeRange = Cells(i, 5)
Dim cartMx As Long
'determine category by first digit of cell
    Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 11).Value, 2))
        Case "E"
            Select Case contTypeRange

                Case "B", "J3", "B0" ' "B" is not recognized
                    cartMx = 4 * contQty
                Case "C", "C0", "J2", "B2" ' "C" is not recognized
                    cartMx = 8 * contQty
                Case "C2", "J1", "j4"
                    cartMx = 16 * contQty
                Case "D1"
                    cartMx = 24 * contQty
                Case "XX", "ZZ"
                    cartMx = 0
                Case Else '"B" and "C" execute here
                    cartMx = contQty
                End Select
 Case "G", "P"
            Select Case contTypeRange
                Case "B", "J3", "B0", "D1"
                    'do nothing
                Case "C", "C0", "J2"
                    cartMx = 6 * contQty
                Case "C2", "J1"
                    cartMx = 12 * contQty
                Case "XX", "ZZ"
                    cartMx = 0
                Case Else
                    cartMx = contQty
                End Select

        Case "A", "A3", "B", "B", "C", "C3", "D", "D3", "D4"
            Select Case contTypeRange
                Case "C", "C0", "J2", "B2"
                    cartMx = 2 * contQty
                Case "C2", "J1"
                    cartMx = 4 * contQty
                Case "D1"
                    cartMx = 6 * contQty
                Case Else
                    cartMx = contQty
                End Select



        Case "T", "F", "R", "L"
            Select Case contTypeRange
                Case "B", "J3", "B0"
                    cartMx = 2 * contQty
                Case "C", "C0", "J2", "B2"
                    cartMx = 4 * contQty
                Case "C2", "J1"
                    cartMx = 8 * contQty
                Case "D1"
                    cartMx = 12 * contQty
                Case "XX", "ZZ"
                    cartMx = 0
                Case Else
                    cartMx = contQty
                End Select
        Case Else
            cartMx = 1 * contQty
    End Select



        cartMaxCalc = cartMx

 End Function
```

Comment: Please post the full function.

Comment: You definitely have some unprintable characters in column E.  So, what you see as "B" has something after it, either spaces or other non printable characters.  In an empty column put `=TRIM(CLEAN(E1))` and copy down.  Then copy and paste the values only of this column over that of column E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your select to:

```
Trim(UCase(Left(Cells(i, 11).Value, 2)))
```

and the second select to

```
Trim(contTypeRange)
```

It looks like you might have extra spaces. If that doesn't work, then check the `contTypeRange` value for length to see if there are some strange characters in it...

Comment: This would still give 2 letters instead of 1, which would never work

Comment: If the second character is a space, it will get 1 character.

Comment: that is completely untrue - do this in the immediate window: `?Len(Left("b ",2))` and you will see the length is still 2 because it returns the "b" *and* the space

Comment: `Trim` removes the spaces on either end.

Comment: @MacroMan but if you put `? Trim("B ") = "B"` in the immediate window it returns true.

Comment: @PKatona my apologies - I completely overlooked the `Trim` function for some reason :S yes you are in fact correct it would return just the one character

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Case UCase(Left(Cells(i, 11).Value, 2)) '// <~~ Get 2 characters from left
    Case "E" '// <~~ Only 1 character long - will never be equal
        Select Case contTypeRange '// <~~ this would never be reached
```

That's getting the first **2** characters of `Cells(i, 11)` which is never going to evaluate to `"E"` so I'm not convinced that execution is occurring anywhere inside that nested `Select Case` statement

Comment: Hmmm... just tried `? ucase(left("b",2))="B"` in an immediate window and it returned true.

Comment: He says it is executing on "E", but not recognizing "B" or "C" in the second select, ergo, there is something in contTypeRange (perhaps "B " or some other character).

Comment: @ScottCraner but do we know that the cell only contains the letter "B" ?

Comment: That would be true, but if the only letter in the cell is `e` or `E` then it would return true and the next `Select Case` would fire.  My guess is that there is a space after first character in `Cells(i, 5)`

Comment: @ScottCraner indeed that could be the case, some simple debugging from the OP would probably help in any case

Comment: To that I agree 100%

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that "B" and "C" are executed in the else? Can you write in the else

`debug.print contTypeRange
 debug.print len(contTypeRange)`

just to see what is it returning?

Comment: @PKatona, your solution worked, Thank you! and all who contributed, I learnt a lot more ways to debug from all of you,   Thanks, thanks, thanks!